# How to get parent administrative boundaries via OverPass API

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Having an administrative boundary relation of certain level, what is the best way to get parent level boundaries?

This works for Bratislava city part Petržalka:
http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/ewU

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,"name","admin_level")];
rel(2208781);
(._;<<;);
out;
```

The result is:

```
@id     @type       name                    admin_level
14296   relation    Slovensko               2
388210  relation    okres Bratislava V      8
388265  relation    Bratislavský kraj       4
1702499 relation    Bratislava              6
2208781 relation    Petržalka               9
```

But it doesn't work for Vienna part Meidling
http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/ex1

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,"name","admin_level")];
rel(1990596);
(._;<<;);
out;
```

the result

```
@id     @type       name        admin_level
1990596 relation    Meidling    9
```

Obviously, the problem is that there are no sub-relations defined in Vienna boundary relations. Is there any reliable way to find these parent-child relations?

Comment: Any solution for this yet?

Comment: @DžanOperta No, sorry, I've abandoned this a long time ago.

Comment: @DžanOperta Look into my answer if you still looking for one.

Answer (score 1):

### Search Near then Down again

It is not the perfect yet, as I still don't know how to make recursive queries.

1. Search for near-by higher administrative. (5Km seems good for close-by towns)

   ```
   [out:csv(::id,::type,"name","admin_level")];
   rel(id:1990596);
   relation["admin_level"~"8|7|6|5|4"](around:5000);
   (._;<<;);
   out;
   ```

   > ```
   > @id   @type   name    admin_level
   > 16239 relation    Österreich  2
   > 77189 relation    Niederösterreich    4
   > 109166    relation    Wien    4
   > 111858    relation    Bezirk Mödling  6
   > 111881    relation    Gemeinde Hennersdorf    8
   > 111887    relation    Gemeinde Breitenfurt bei Wien   8
   > 111946    relation    Gemeinde Perchtoldsdorf 8
   > 111948    relation    Brunn am Gebirge    8
   > 111956    relation    Gemeinde Vösendorf  8
   > 2668952   relation    European Union / Union Européenne / Europäische Union   
   > 12729625  relation    Eurozone / Zone euro    
   > 13376469  relation    Member States of the European Union / États members de l'Union européenne / Mitgliedstaaten der Europäischen Union
   > ```
2. Look for lower administrative inside each to verify

   ```
   [out:csv(::id,::type,"name","admin_level")];
   area["name"="Wien"]["admin_level"="4"]->.target_area;
   relation["admin_level"~"9|8|7|6|5"](area.target_area);
   (._;<<;);
   out;
   ```

   > ```
   > @id   @type   name    admin_level
   > 1990590   relation    Alsergrund  9
   > 1990591   relation    Hietzing    9
   > 1990592   relation    Innere Stadt    9
   > 1990593   relation    Josefstadt  9
   > 1990594   relation    Leopoldstadt    9
   > 1990595   relation    Mariahilf   9
   > 1990596   relation    Meidling    9
   > 1990597   relation    Neubau  9
   > 1990598   relation    Penzing 9
   > 1990599   relation    Rudolfsheim-Fünfhaus    9
   > 1990600   relation    Währing 9
   > 1991416   relation    Landstraße  9
   > 1991433   relation    Brigittenau 9
   > 1991434   relation    Donaustadt  9
   > 1991435   relation    Döbling 9
   > 1991436   relation    Favoriten   9
   > 1991437   relation    Floridsdorf 9
   > 1991438   relation    Hernals 9
   > 1991439   relation    Liesing 9
   > 1991440   relation    Margareten  9
   > 1991441   relation    Ottakring   9
   > 1991442   relation    Simmering   9
   > 1991443   relation    Wieden  9
   > 3980995   relation    Amtshaus für den 16. Bezirk 9
   > ```

### Long term solution

Best is still to contribute back directly and update parent relation. It wouldn't take much as long Wikidata/Wikipedia already has such info public.  Or at least submit a OSM "note" on Meidling so someone has knowledge may fix it.

### Update: not good enough yet

Using foreach, https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1B5X

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,"name","admin_level")];

rel(id:2208781)->.t;

rel["admin_level"~"9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2"](around.t:5000)->.n;
//.n out;
foreach.n ->.e(
  .e map_to_area->.ea;
  rel(id:2208781)(area.ea)->.c;
  if (c.count(relations))
  {
    .e out;
  };
);
```

> ```
> @id   @type   name    admin_level
> 14296 relation    Slovensko   2
> 388265    relation    Bratislavský kraj   4
> 1702499   relation    Bratislava  6
> 14613937  relation    Bratislavská arcidiecéza    6
> 388210    relation    okres Bratislava V  8
> 2208781   relation    Petržalka   9
> ```

Other town: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1B5Y

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,"name","admin_level")];

rel(id:1990596)->.t;

rel["admin_level"~"9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2"](around.t:5000)->.n;
//.n out;
foreach.n ->.e(
  .e map_to_area->.ea;
  rel(id:1990596)(area.ea)->.c;
  if (c.count(relations))
  {
    .e out;
  };
);
```

> ```
> @id   @type   name    admin_level
> 16239 relation    Österreich  2
> 109166    relation    Wien    4
> ```